# Common keyboard shortcuts for zsh zle and bash readline

Tags: bash, zsh, readline

I use zsh as my shell, but there are a lot of commandline programs which use readline. I also like to configure different keyboard shortcuts (e.g. ctrl backspace and ctrl delete).

Is there a way to share keyboard shortcuts for both the zle configuration and .inputrc, by only specifying them once in some file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, no. Most keys are not bound to sequences of characters, but specific functions implemented by `readline` or by `zle`. Also, `zsh` doesn't have a configuration file like `.inputrc`; you just write a script that calls `bindkey` a lot. (Similary, you can write a `bash` script that calls `bind`, which creates key bindings used by `bash` but not other programs that use `readline`.)